# vtkMolecule - remove atom

Tags: c++, vtk, molecule

I am working on program which builds molecule from scratch. My intention is to use `vtkMolecule` for it. However, while it is easy to add Atom to molecule by `AppendAtom` method, there seems to be no function for removal.

**Here is my code:**

```
int main(int, char *[]) {
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMolecule> molecule =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMolecule>::New();   
  molecule->AppendAtom(12, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  molecule->AppendAtom(12, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  molecule->AppendAtom(12, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);

  molecule->AppendBond(molecule->GetAtom(0), molecule->GetAtom(1), 1);
  molecule->AppendBond(molecule->GetAtom(1), molecule->GetAtom(2), 1);

  //hypothetical code, I want something like this - remove atom by id:
  molecule->RemoveAtom(2)

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMoleculeMapper> moleculeMapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMoleculeMapper>::New();
  moleculeMapper->SetInputData(molecule);
  //...rendering etc.
}
```

[vtkMolecule Class Reference](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMolecule.html)

I was thinking of some `vtkGraph` method like `vtkGraph::RemoveVertexInternal`, but it is (probably for some reason) protected  and therefore not usable in child of child class.

**My question is:**

Is there a simple way to delete atom from molecule other than creating child class of `vtkMolecule` with specialized method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no simple method to do that.

Protected means that it is usable from a child class but not externally that's why you need to create a new public method, like `RemoveAtom(id)`, that call `RemoveVertexInternal(id)`.
You should either subclass `vtkMolecule` or just patch it.

Is suggest you to patch and to contribute upstream: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/merge_requests